# Contributive page where people logged in can write

Tags: plugins, posts, login, forms

I'd like to have a page on my wordpress site where people can add a content really simply. They would click on a link that open a popup where they can login, add a content, and that's it. It would be published once i have validated it.

Do you think there is a solution?

Thanks to all.

Comment: You can use either WP User Posts plugin or ImagePress plugin - https://getbutterfly.com/wordpress-plugins/imagepress/ - they will do the job perfectly.